# Functions at specific click with click counter at one div button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a mini JavaScript game. I want a series of effects and functions to occur at certain amount of clicks via a click counter, via one `#div` button.

I am getting pretty close in terms of getting my sought effects to happen within the functions, but I need to organize it in accordance to clicks and number of clicks and to happen without errors with ONE `#div` button. So, essentially tying all of these functions to one button without problem.

I need a click counter, presumably. `EG, Click 1 = This function fires. Click 2 = This function fires.` Currently most of my functions work, but fire all scrambled. **Need these functions to fire, specific to the click count. So, needing to count and store the click counts as well.**

Any pointers?

Below is how it's shaping:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$var a1_Events = [function1, function2, function3, function4, function5, function6, function7, function8],
    a1_c = 0;


function function1(){
  alert('SHAKING!');
}

function function2(){
  alert('BZZZZZZZZZZZ!');
}

function function3(){
  $("#area1").click(function(){
    $("#area1").hide();
    $("#area2").show();
  });
}

function function4(){
  $("#area2").click(function(){
    $("#area1").show();
    $("#area2").hide();
  });
}

function function5(){
  alert('YES!');
}

function function6(){
$("#area1").click(function(){
  $("#bg_div").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
  $("#bg_skew").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
   });
}

function function7(){
  alert('NO!');
}

function function8(){
$("#area1").click(function(){
  $("#area1").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
  $("#area2").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
  $("#sound1").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
   });
}

$('#area1').click(function(){
   a1_Events[a1_c++ % a1_Events.length]();
  });
});
```

---

& Yes. I am trying to allow *one* div to act as the main 'button' so to speak, to allow these functions to fire per click. First click, BOOM, this function occurs, Second click BAM, this function occurs, and so forth. Possibly by storing and keeping track of the click counts. And again, firing on specific click 'x' not EVERY click.

Comment: The something, something2 and tilt functions don't start the expected effect, they just set up click listeners?

Comment: You've got `function tilt()` twice. Only one is valid.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi My current question is how to allow my functions ONLY to occur at a certain amount of clicks and / or adding a click counter to create this solution.

Comment: `function3` and `function8` will attach new listeners to the `#area1` every time, which will fire on *every* click. Is that really intended?

Comment: @Bergi no, But I am trying to allow one div to act as the main 'button' so to speak to allow these functions to fire per click. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already got it doing what you want with this:

```
$('#area1').click(function () {
   a1_Events[a1_c++ % a1_Events.length]();
});
```

But then, as [Bergi pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453735/functions-at-specific-click-with-click-counter-at-one-div-button#comment25358716_17453735), some of your click handlers bind other click handlers.  Once those are called, you'll have multiple functions being called with each click.  Change those functions to not bind new click handlers, but just perform the action.  For example, `function3()` should be:

```
function function3() {
    $("#area1").hide();
    $("#area2").show();
}
```

Change `function6()` and `function8()` in the same way.  Remove `function4()` as a click handler for `#area1`.  It will never be called because it isn't set to be called until after `function3()`, which hides `#area1`, making it unclickable.  Just bind the click event for `#area2` directly in the document ready handler.  You have `$var a1_Events`.  I assume that's just a typo.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a1_Events = [function1, function2, function3, function5, function6, function7, function8],
        a1_c = 0;
    function function1() {
        alert('SHAKING!');
    }
    function function2() {
        alert('BZZZZZZZZZZZ!');
    }
    function function3() {
        $("#area1").hide();
        $("#area2").show();
    }
    function function5() {
        alert('YES!');
    }
    function function6() {
        $("#bg_div").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
        $("#bg_skew").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
    }
    function function7() {
        alert('NO!');
    }
    function function8() {
        $("#area1").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
        $("#area2").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
        $("#sound1").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
    }
    $('#area1').click(function () {
        a1_Events[a1_c++ % a1_Events.length]();
    });
    $("#area2").click(function () {
        $("#area1").show();
        $("#area2").hide();
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/uWVAb](http://jsfiddle.net/uWVAb/)

Comment: so, thanks a million! This works and is excellent and all, and definitely helps but I need these functions to fire, specific to the click count. So, needing to count and store the click counts as well.

Comment: The click count is stored in the variable `a1_c`.